# SMTP error on iis hosting codeigniter

Tags: php, email, iis, smtp, codeigniter-3

I'm developing a web page, wich contains a contact form, all this on codeigniter last version. When I try to send a message using Google smtp, it throws me the following error:

> Can't send email using smtp php, maybe your server is not properly configured to use this send method.

CONTROLLER

```
public function send()
{
  $this->load->library('Recaptcha');
   $this->load->library('email');

   if( $this->input->is_ajax_request()){

        $captcha_answer = $this->input->post('g-recaptcha-response');

      $result = $this->validar($captcha_answer);

      if ($result == 1) {
            $mail = $this->input->post('contact_mail');
            $name = $this->input->post('contact_name');
            $msg = $this->input->post('contact_message');


            $config = array(

            'protocol' => 'smtp',
            'smtp_host'=> 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
            'smtp_port'=> 465,
            'smtp_user'=> 'sebastian.m.e89@gmail.com',
            'smtp_pass'=> '*********',
            'mailtype'=>  'html',
            'charset'=>   'utf-8',
            'newline' =>  '\r\n'
           );

           $this->email->initialize($config);

           $this->email->from($mail);
           $this->email->to('sebastian.m.e89@gmail.com');
           $this->email->from($mail);
           $this->email->subject('IMPORTANTE-CORREO CONTACTO');
           $this->email->message('<h2>PĂGINA NOVADERMA</h2>
                            <hr><br>
                            <br>
                            <p>'.$msg.'</p>
           ');

           if ($this->email->send()) {
             echo json_encode('todo bien wacho');
           }
    }
    else {
    }
   }
}

 public function validar($captcha_answer)
 {    
$this->load->library('Recaptcha');
$response = $this->recaptcha->verifyResponse($captcha_answer);

if ($response['success']) {
    return 1;
  }
  else {
    return 0;
  }
 }
```

The server is running under IIS...so I have no idea how fix this error, it's an error of codeigniter?...any help is usefull, cheers.

Comment: If u r sending email from local host you also have make change in php.ini file

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/a/40954947/4371020